# Weird content-assist behavior in Eclipse with Android

Tags: android, eclipse, content-assist

I have encountered very weird behavior on Eclipse's (both Helios and Juno) content-assist when I was programming for Android. Following capture shows everything smooth when I was still inside that inner class (OnSeekBarChangeListener())

[image]

Then once I move further on (just one line forward, declaring an int after the Listener instead of inside, as shown below, content-assist has stopped working!

[image]

Then commenting out the whole listener makes things work again...

[image]

I tried deleting the whole block of code and hand type them again yet the behavior remains. I have tried cleaning out Eclipse's cahche (-clean), double-checked my content-assist setting (seems to be correct otherwise case #1 & 3 wouldn't have worked)

Strange thing is that I had another inner listener earlier in the file and things were working without any problem.

What can be the problem? (it's almost impossible to write code without content-assist :p)

Thanks in advance for your assistances.

Michael